# Is my custom operator for sorting in python correct?

Tags: python

I want to sort object list named schedules according to arrivalT. if arrivalT is equal, I want to sort according to burst, if arrivalT and bursT both equal I want to sort according to id. Is my custom comparitor implementaion correct?

````
from functools import cmp_to_key
class Pair:
    def __init__(self, id, arrivalT, burstT):
        self.id = id
        self.arrivalT = arrivalT
        self.burstT = burstT
def compare(p1, p2):
    if p1.arrivalT < p2.arrivalT:
        return -1
    elif p1.arrivalT < p2.arrivalT:
        return 1
    else:
        if p1.burstT < p1.burstT:
            return -1
        elif p1.burstT > p2.burstT:
            return 1
        else:
            if p1.id < p2.id:
                return -1
            elif p1.id > p2.id:
                return 1

n = len(id)
schedules = []
for i in range(n):
    schedules.append(Pair(id[i], arrival[i], burst[i]))
schedules = sorted(schedules, key = cmp_to_key(compare))
for i in schedules:
    print(i.id, i.arrivalT, i.burstT)
id =[1, 2, 3, 4]
arrival = [2, 0, 4, 5]
burst = [3, 4, 2, 4 ]
shortestJobFirst(id, arrival, burst)

```
````

Comment: In terms of correctness insofar as correct results, you need to be at least somewhat confident that your implementation is correct before this is eligible for review. The purpose of review isn't to validate correctness, it's to talk about how well-structured the implementation is, standards adherence, etc.

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 3):

## Tips and changes

1. Python has a style guide [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) which explains in excruciating detail how to structure your code. I whole heartily recommend skimming through it and follow it.

   For instance `shortesJobFirst(id, arrival, burst)` *appears* (it is hard to know) to be a function, but functions in python are - according to PEP 8 - written in lowercase seperated by underscores. E.g `shortesJobFirst -> shortest_job_first`. However if `shortesJobFirst` is a class, you are good =)
2. You should use the [`if __name__ == "__main__":`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) module in your answer.
3. Your naming practices are somewhat lacking, what does `Pair` mean? A better name would perhaps have been `Job`.
4. It is tough suggesting better names, as you lack a short explanation of what your code does. This is done by using [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)
5. The printing could be improved by using [pythons awesome formating options](https://pyformat.info/)
6. Why use a class at all when a [`namedtuple()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) can do the same job?
7. Why implement a sorting function when you can use `attrgetter` from [`operators`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html)?
8. Use a basic linter for your code, this ensures you have correct spacings and indents. As mentioned it is common to have two spaces between classes and functions.

## Improvements

```
from collections import namedtuple
from operator import attrgetter


def sort_jobs_by_attributes(jobs, attributes):
    """
    This functions sorts the jobs (namedtuples) according to the attribute_lst. If

             attribute_lst = ["arrival_time", "burst_time", "id"]

    We then first sort by arrival_time, on tie we
                  sort by burst_time, on tie we
                  sort by id
    """
    for attribute in reversed(attributes):
        jobs.sort(key=attrgetter(attribute))
    return jobs


JOB_ATTRIBUTES = ["arrival_time", "burst_time", "id"]
Job = namedtuple("Job", JOB_ATTRIBUTES)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    job_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    arrival_times = [4, 1, 4, 1]
    burst_times = [3, 4, 2, 4]

    jobs = [
        Job(*job_details) for job_details in zip(arrival_times, burst_times, job_ids)
    ]

    sort_jobs_by_attributes(jobs, JOB_ATTRIBUTES)

    for job in jobs:
        print(job)
```

**Side note:** you don't need to provide any key function. The default behavior of tuples (and by extension, namedtuples, since they are a subclass) is to sort element-wise. That means that the first elements of the two tuples are compared, and if there's a tie then the second elements are compared, and so on. Since the name is the first element, all you need is `sorted(jobs)`.

```
from collections import namedtuple

JOB_ATTRIBUTES = ["arrival_time", "burst_time", "id"]
Job = namedtuple("Job", JOB_ATTRIBUTES)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    job_ids = [1, 2, 3, 4]
    arrival_times = [4, 1, 4, 1]
    burst_times = [3, 4, 2, 4]
    job_details = [arrival_times, burst_times, job_ids]

    jobs = sorted(
        Job(*details) for details in zip(*job_details)
    )

    for job in jobs:
        print(job)
```

Note that implicitly sorting the tuple can be a bit spooky if you later decide the change around the order. In addition to make it harder to see *exactly* what is being sorted. I will leave it up to you to make the final call on which version is the best.

Comment: This is a good review. Can be done in one sort call, if so inclined: `sort(key = lambda j: tuple(getattr(j, a) for a in attributes))`.

Comment: @FMc good comment. In fact you do not need any keys ;-) See the edit above.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested in another review, you could write a specific function to sort the
objects as you like in this one use case. Or you could package these objects up
as `namedtuple` instances, and just sort them directly. But you might not want
to convert to `nametuple` (maybe your class needs some other behaviors). In
that case, you have a few options.

One is to use a `dataclass` and arrange the attributes in the order than you
want sorting to occur. This approach is similar to the `nametuple` strategy in
the sense that you must declare the attributes in the desired sorting-order.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen = True, order = True)
class Job:
    arrivalT: int
    burstT: int
    id: int
```

Another option is to define the `__lt__()` method in the class, so that
Python's built-in sorting functions can compare the objects directly.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Job:
    id: int
    arrivalT: int
    burstT: int

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return (
            (self.arrivalT, self.burstT, self.id) <
            (other.arrivalT, other.burstT, other.id)
        )
```

Or if you need more flexibility at runtime, you could write a general purpose
function to allow you to sort any objects based on any combination of
attributes. This approach would make more sense in situations where you don't
know in advance how things should be sorted.

```
@dataclass(frozen = True)
class Job:
    id: int
    arrivalT: int
    burstT: int

def attrs_getter(*attributes):
    return lambda x: tuple(getattr(x, a) for a in attributes)

# Usage example.
jobs = [Job(1, 4, 3), Job(2, 1, 4), Job(3, 4, 2), Job(4, 1, 4)]
jobs.sort(key = attrs_getter('arrivalT', 'burstT', 'id'))
```

Comment: Great answer! I particularly liked hooking into `__lt__`. I just want to mention that my first snippet works perfectly fine using a class as well. I just found it convinient in this case to switch to a named tuple =)